# How can i install node_modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, npm

I used `npm i` command to install node_modules in my vue.js project, but I am getting the error shown below:

> ```
> npm ERR! code E404   
> npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@fds%2flima-ticket-validator - Not found   
> npm ERR! 404   
> npm ERR! 404  '@fds/lima-ticket-validator@^2.0.0' is not in the npm registry.   
> npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)   
> npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'cef_frontend'   
> npm ERR! 404   
> npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a   
> npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
> ```

Comment: What does the package.json line look like for that dependency? `"@fds/lima-ticket-validator" : "^2.0.0"` ? You haven't put the version number in the package name somehow? (You may have to look in cef_frontend for this.)

Comment: And are you expecting to get that from the central NPM registry, or a local server instead? I can't find a project called lima-ticket-validator there or on GitHub. Ditto cef_frontend - is that a local project too?

Comment: please post package.json

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: Yeah, its working. Thank u so much.

Comment: But, what is "@fds/lima-ticket-validator" : "^2.0.0" ?

Comment: Yes, i am doing under corporate server.

Answer (score 0):

The `@fds/lima-ticket-validator` package doesn't exist on the public NPM registry. Is it possible this is an internal package hosted by your companies internal registry?

You may need to do something like:

```
npm config set registry https://example.your-registry.com/
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fds/lima-ticket-validator